# Alfresco source code : alfresco-android-app. How to customize the application?

Tags: android, mobile, alfresco, mobile-application

I have downloaded the Alfresco [source code for mobile android](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-android-app), then I unzipped the file
and imported it into Android studio. Now I have to do certain customization.

When I build the application it is ok, but when I run the application it appears on the AVD but is not starting?

This message appears, what can I do ?

[image: Message of error when i start the application on my device]

Comment: How are you building and packaging the app?

Comment: thank you martin for your help, but what would you tell me by " how "? you want a picture to see the architecture of the code ? or you want to know how i do to build and if i put the configurations  prerequisites for the build ? thank you

Comment: ok i have found the problem, you have to do all the configurations prerequisites on the alfresco documentation : https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-android-app/wiki/Getting-Started  and you have to comment on build.gradle(module:alfresco-mobile-android) this one : //debugCompile project(':extensions:hockeyapp')